# Access to methods and variables in other classes/objects (where are the objects btw)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, encapsulation

Ok, I am new to Objective-C/iPhone programming, so there are some questions arising when I try to do things that would be quite easy in C++.

I´m building a tab bar based iPhone application with three views, one for each tab bar button. In the first view the user builds a NSdictionary, which the second view shall display as a graph. To access this dictionary, I save it to a .plist in the first view controller, then bulding a new dictionary from this .plist in the second.

To make the graph view, i use s7graphview, which is initialized etc in SecondViewController, but has its own .h and .m files, which I import. The method to load values into the graph (which is from the created dictionary), is implemented in the GraphInfoList.m file, which means I have to make another dictionary from the .plist to access the data. How can I access the already created dictionary?

While doing this, I also made a method "dataFilePath", which returns the file path of the .plist, which I use to load the data into a dictionary. I have found no other way of implementing this method than to copy/paste it to every .m file that uses it! There´s got to be another way?

An while I´m at it: where are the objects in iPhone programming? The .m files is classes, aren´t they? I never create a new object using the new operator, and I thought I may would be able to access the methods if I had any object to call (like [FirstViewController dataFilePath] ).

I really don´t know how this is handled in Obj-C/Cocoa, and I don´t know what to search for to find the answers. Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem using s7graphview in a different view controller. I solved it by adding an NSDictionary as a property in the AppDelegate and when the viewwilldisappear method fires i added this code:

```
[((MyAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) setDictionary:self.dictionary];
```

I think it isn't the only way to do it but you will remove the .plist code who slows you app

Answer (score 1):

An object is an instance of a class (a .m file).  You alloc/init a new object like you do in java with the new operator. you can import the .h of a class you want to use/have access to in and then use something like

```
MyClass *objectInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

to create an instance.

As far as the dataFilePath method... you can just have it in your app's delegate (probably something like MyAppNameAppDelegate.m) which is a singleton (one instance for the entire app).  you can then get the file path using:

```
myFilePath = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dataFilePath];
```

I would suggest looking into a beginning objective-c book for more information. I'd suggest [Learn Objective-C on the Mac](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150). Also, I would take a look at a basic introduction to Object Oriented Programming, as it seems this is what is tripping you up more than anything. Good luck.

Comment: There is usually a 1-1 mapping between classes and `.m`-files. But this is not a requirement. You can implement several classes in the same `.m`-file, or as I usually do spread the implementation of one class to several `.m`-files. The class is when you type `@interface Name : Superclass`, no matter where you type it.

Comment: yes, good point, I was just trying to quickly refer to how he thought about it.

Comment: Thanks, trying to put the function in the app delegate now, and do like this:
In the appDelegate.h:

-(NSString *) dataFilePath;
.m:
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
}

When I call 
NSString *myFilePath = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dataFilePath]; in FirstViewController.m it says method -dataFilePath not found... What´s wrong?

Comment: you need to make sure you #include "MyAppDelegate.h" in any .m you use it.

Comment: I have #import "MyApp_AppDelegate.h" in FirsViewController.h, do I need to import in the .m as well? EDIT: Does not work even when I import the "appDelegate.h" in the .m file :S

Comment: try casting it like this (though you shouldn't have to really..) [ ( (MyAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] ) dataFilePath];

Answer (score 0):

Your app delegate is a good place to share things. you can keep the data file path function in your app delegate and access it

```
path = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] dataFilePath];
```

Dont forget to #import "YourAppDelegate.h" file.

.m files are like .cpp files or .c files. Basically, implementation files.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `NSDictionary` is a bad replacement for proper domain objects, you get problems when juggling your keys. And often objects are not the best way to model your data, for example numbers as `NSNumber` is just cumbersome.

Instead introduce a proper domain class. There is not problem in letting both via controllers in your tab bar have access to the same object, you can easily use the `viewWillAppear:` method to update states from one view to the other.

There might even be a time when you want a singleton. If there can be only one logical instance of any object, the singleton is the way to go. Don't fear them. Usually a lazy patters just as Apple use in their frameworks is what you want. With for example this interface:

```
@interface MyDomainManager : NSObject { /* ivars here */ }

+(MyDomainManager*)sharedManager;

// More proper tie and method here    

@end
```

And then an implementation like this:

```
@implementation MyDomainManager

+(MyDomainManager*)sharedManager;
{
    static MyDomainManager* manager = nil;
    if (manager == nil) {
        manager = [[self alloc] init];
    }
    return manager;
}

// More implementation cruft…

@end
```

Starting out simple as this is a good start, and then build from there.